# React Native: Push notifications not working in active app

Tags: firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications

I have updated firebase to v5 to v6
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0-rc4",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^6.4.0-rc4",
and also using "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
the issue I am getting is that push notifications are not working in active app while app is open but working fine when app in not active
[image]

Comment: Were you able to fix this?